# Java multiple files and folder hierarchy

Tags: java, class, object, compiler-errors, package

I have multiple Java files, one of them (Demo) is where most of the functions are and DemoTest1 is where the main is.
I tried packaging the Demo file and using the package at the other files but when I compile with the terminal (javac ...), DemoTest1 doesn't compile as it also has a function that has a parameter, and return value that is an object of the Demo file.

Demo.java file:

```
package xyz.mypackage;

class  Demo{
    private  double val1;
    private  double val2;

    private void  setValues(double num1, double num2){
        val1 = num1;
        val2 = num2;
    }
    private double getValue1(){
        return (this.val1);
    }
    private double getValue2(){
        return (this.val2);
    }
    private double  getAverage(){
       return((this.val1 + this.val2) / 2);
    }

    public Demo(double double1, double double2){
        this.val1 = double1;
        this.val2 = double2;
    }

    static void decrDemo(Demo obj){
        obj.setValues(obj.val1 - 1, obj.val2 - 1);
    }
}
```

DemoTest1.java file:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import xyz.mypackage.Demo;

public class DemoTest1{
    static Demo addDemo(Demo obj1, Demo obj2){
        return new Demo(obj1.getValue1() + obj2.getValue1(), obj1.getValue2() + obj2.getValue2());
    }

    static void incrDemo(Demo obj){
        obj.setValues(obj.getValue1() + 5, obj.getValue2() + 5);
    }

    public static void main(){
        Demo item = Demo();

        System.out.printl("\nPlease enter 2 numbers: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double val1 = input.nextDouble();
        double val2 = input.nextDouble();
        demo.setValues(val1, val2);

        System.out.printl("\nThe average of the two values entered is: " + item.getAverage());

        Demo obj1 = new Demo(5, 7),
             obj2 = new Demo(14, 9);

        Demo objR = addDemo(obj1, obj2);

        incrDemo(obj1);

        System.out.printl("\nobjR has the following values. val1: &d\tval2: &d", objR.getValue1(), objR.getValue2());
        System.out.printl("\nobj1 has the following values. val1: &d\tval2: &d", obj1.getValue1(), obj1.getValue2());
    }
}
```

Error output:

```
Air:Project xyz$ javac Demo.java DemoTest1.java
DemoTest1.java:2: xyz.mypackage.Demo is not public in xyz.mypackage;     
cannot be accessed from outside package
import xyz.mypackage.Demo;
                    ^
./Demo.java:3: duplicate class: xyz.mypackage.Demo
class  Demo
^
DemoTest1.java:6: cannot access Demo
bad class file: ./Demo.java
file does not contain class Demo
Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of    
the classpath.
static Demo addDemo(Demo obj1, Demo obj2)
```

If i'm following the instructions right, it should be running but I guess, Demo doesn't get included in DemoTest1, which I don't understand because I used packaging. Or do I need to compile files differently than using javac .. on each of them and then running DemoTest1 with java .. ?

**Edit:** Changing folder hierarchy and fixing syntax errors made it to successfully compile but when trying to run it (java DemoTest1) I get this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main
```

**Edit2:** Exception has been fixed. Thought main() is enough but it requires main(String args[]).
Now it works perfect, just as it was intended. I appreciate the help and the opportunity to learn!

**Solution:** For anyone looking for similar problems. I wrote xyz.mypackage when using the package so it had to be in those folders/subfolders (I thought, that it is itself the regular syntax to package, regardless of folder), also a default constructor had to be added because I added a special constructor and I wrongly thought that if there are no parameters, it will just use the regular one. 
Another problem other than some minor syntax errors (not using println correctly or using %d instead of &f, etc), was that main() can not be left empty, it needs to have a parameter (String args[]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class DemoTest1 {
    static Demo addDemo(Demo obj1, Demo obj2) {
        return new Demo(obj1.getValue1() + obj2.getValue1(), 
                obj1.getValue2() + obj2.getValue2());
    }

    static void incrDemo(Demo obj) {
        obj.setValues(obj.getValue1() + 5, obj.getValue2() + 5);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Demo item = new Demo(0, 0);

        System.out.println("\nPlease enter 2 numbers: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double val1 = input.nextDouble();
        double val2 = input.nextDouble();
        item.setValues(val1, val2);

        System.out.println("\nThe average of the two values entered is: " 
                + item.getAverage());

        Demo obj1 = new Demo(5, 7);
        Demo obj2 = new Demo(14, 9);

        Demo objR = addDemo(obj1, obj2);

        incrDemo(obj1);

        System.out.printf("\nobjR has the following values. val1: %.2f\tval2: %.2f", 
                objR.getValue1(), objR.getValue2());
        System.out.printf("\nobj1 has the following values. val1: %.2f\tval2: %.2f", 
                obj1.getValue1(), obj1.getValue2());
    }
}
```

The demo class is fine but try it this way it should work. There were a few syntax errors in the test class. To call a double you use `%.2f` for a double with 2 decimal places, instead of what you had. Also you don't need to put them in a new package or anything like that.

Comment: Thank you, I though &d would be enough for a decimal. I also did not know that it is required to include arguments for main.
It works beautiful now, and while researching I learnt again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare Demo class **as public**. If you can check the error, it does explicitly mention the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be a few problems here:

in DemoTest1 you should change

```
import xyz.mypackage.Demo;
```

to

```
import xyz.mypackage.Demo.*;
```

and

```
demo.setValues(val1, val2);
```

to

```
 item.setValues(val1, val2);
```

In Demo you should change

```
class  Demo
```

to

```
public class Demo
```

and add a default constructor because you reference one in your DemoTest1 file

something like

```
public Demo() {
    val1 = 0.0
    val2 = 0.0
}
```

Comment: Yepp, just fixed those. Getting there. There were syntax errors and the folder hierarchy was wrong.
Now it compiles but when trying to run it, I get a new error..